# Scaling and translating an image with ScaleType.MATRIX

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I'm working on cropping of the image and I'm using the Matrix scale type since I need to move and rotate the image around. The problem is that at the beginning the image is zoomed out and positioned at the top of the imageView. I have tried a lot of things but none worked.

I tried working with matrices

```
Matrix originalZoomMatrix = new Matrix();
originalZoomMatrix.postTranslate((viewWidth - bitmap.getWidth())/2, (viewHeight - bitmap.getHeight())/2);
originalZoomMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
```

I also tried using RectF

```
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
```

Thanks

Comment: and what does not work with `setRectToRect`? is it still identity matrix?

Comment: It doesn't center it, it goes off screen.

Comment: log the matrix out and check its values, what are imageWidth, imageHeight and imageView dims?

Comment: ImageView { width 1080 = ; height = 1533 }, bitmap { width = 1248; height = 2207}

Comment: and the matrix values?

Comment: Matrix{[0.9, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.9, 461.4][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

Comment: they should be Matrix{[0.6946081, 0.0, 106.564545][0.0, 0.6946081, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}, `Log.d` both `RectF`s when calling `setRectToRect`

Comment: Yeah, actually you're right. Those are the correct values. These are from using postTranslate